# Non inverting OpAmp with NPN amplification factor > 1

Tags: operational-amplifier, npn, voltage-amplification

I need to amplify the output range of a DAC chip from (0-3.3 V) to (0-10 V). Unfortunately, I cannot simply use an inverting OpAmp circuit, because the output needs to stay positive with respect to digital GND.

Is it possible to use an NPN transistor in the feedback circuit, in order to achieve the amplification factor of 3? I ran simulations with LTSpice, and below circuit gave me the expected results - R3 is supposed to lazily simulate the input impedance of the device to be controlled by 0 to 10 V. Frequency of the operation is below 1 kHz.

[image]

[image]

I am not an electronics engineer and am seeking for advice, for perhaps better alternatives.

Comment: Have you considered a simple non-inverting amplifier configuration?

Comment: Why do you need a transistor - is your load very low in resistance?

Comment: NPN is not needed.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, because I did a lot of reading before starting the project, and perhaps I became a bit confused. I learned that the max. amplification factor of non-inverting op-amp circuit is 1, while I need 3.

Comment: @Andyaka, no, the load is the 0..10 V control input of a device, input impedance is apprx. 100kΩ.

Comment: The minimum gain of a non inverting amp is 1

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdlpTp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You need a non-inverting amplifier circuit with a resistor ratio of 2:1.

Gain is 1 + R1/R2 = 1 + 20K/10K = 3.

[image]

The resistors are standard E96 values, so you can use 1% parts or better if you like.

Comment: I simulated a similar circuit with the same simulation result, then I started to solder it, and the actual circuit was limited to amplification factor 1. I only employed for R1/R2 a 50k trim poti. Perhaps, I made a mistake. I will re-solder it with your layout.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftxJXm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>